# About the relationship between 「ので」 and 「~てください」:

Tags: syntax, conjunctions

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", ので cannot be used in sentences that contains a request in the main clause.

However, in many phrases at sites or another grammar books I have found cases like this:

ちょっと気分が悪いので、早く帰らせてください。

After that, I made a quick search on the Internet and noticed that the combination of " ~ので, ~てください" is not uncommon at all, although I have not reached at any conclusion about the reason. Is this gramitical rule simply ignored by most Japaneses, or there are special cases when the use of the pattern " ~ので, ~てください" is valid?